# Setting and removing ToolTips in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm having an issue that I just can't get figured out.

I have a WPF window that is a representation of a physical keyboard used in a POS application. Each physical button is represented by a WPF button.  The user will click on a button which opens another window with controls to change the function that is assigned to it.  When the user hovers over the button, a tooltip is displayed showing the currently assigned function.

After the new settings are set, I need to refresh the toolTips.  The new tooltips appear correctly, but the old ones do not remove.  If I use `Button.ToolTip = null`, all the tool tips disappear.  If I use `Button.ToolTip = String.Empty`, I get a blank tooTip.  I don't want any tooltip displayed if there is not function assigned to the button.

How do I simply remove / deactivate the toolTip when there is nothing to show?

loadToolTips() is fired during the Window_Activated event in the parent window.

Code:

```
private void loadToolTips()
        {
            JPOSDB db = new JPOSDB();
            SqlDataReader dr = default(SqlDataReader);
            StringBuilder tt = new StringBuilder();

            dr = db.getDR("SELECT KeyName, FunctionName, Parameter1, Parameter2 FROM KeyboardSettings JOIN KeyboardFunctions ON KeySetting = FunctionID WHERE KeyboardID = " + runTime.keyboardID);

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                foreach (Control ctrl in grdButtons.Children)
                {
                    if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(Button))
                    {
                        Button button = new Button();
                        button = (Button)ctrl;
                        button.ToolTip = null;   <--- Causes all tool tips to disappear

                        if (button.Name.ToString() == dr[0].ToString())
                        {
                            tt.Clear();
                            tt.Append("Function: " + dr[1].ToString());

                            if (dr[2].ToString().Length > 0)
                            {
                                tt.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                                tt.Append("Value: " + dr[2].ToString());
                            }

                            if (dr[3].ToString().Length > 0)
                            {
                                tt.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                                tt.Append("Name: " + dr[3].ToString());
                            }

                            button.ToolTip = tt.ToString();                    
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            dr.Close();
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*If I use Button.ToolTip = null, all the tool tips disappear*"? For me, setting it to null doesn't influence the other ones. Isn't that the effect you seek? I can post the sample code I'm using.

Comment: If the button is assigned to a function in the DB then the tool tip lists the function, otherwise there should be no tooltip.  If I use Tooltip = null, then there are no tool tips, even if the button is assigned. Stepping through the code shows that button.ToolTip = tt.ToString() is executed, but the tooltip does not display.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ClearValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597464%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to clear the Depencency ToolTipProperty. See if this helps.

```
 Button button = (Button)ctrl;
 button.ClearValue(Button.ToolTipProperty);
```

Comment: This has the same effect as using `Button.ToolTip = null;` - No tooltips show up at all. Thank you for the suggestion, its a good one to know.

Comment: @Kerberos42 There must be something that I am missing, are you saying that it is clearing all of the ToolTips for every button? If so the problem is in your foreach loop because the ClearValue only clears the Tooltip for that specific Button.

Comment: Yes, it clears it for the specific button, but it loops through all the buttons and clears them all.  However, after the .ClearValue method, the .ToolTip property is then set if the button name matches a field in the database.  The toolTip property is still null after this happens.

Comment: @Kerberos42 See if the corresponding SetValue works.  `button.SetValue(Button.ToolTipProperty, tt);` In the demo that I setup when I cleared the ToolTip I was still able to set it. It is almost like you are iterating through your collection twice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood the question, but you can use this line:

```
var s = tt.ToString();
button.ToolTip = string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? null : s;
```

If this doesn't answer your question, please leave a comment and I'll remove it.